# If you add one char to a Question, the edit history says it's adding 5

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, revisions-list

No big deal, but if you add one char to a question, the edit history says it's adding 5.

Thought you should know.

Comment: So, would this be status-norepro, because adding one character really does add one character, or status-bydesign, because the system is designed to include the whitespace in the character count?  Going no-repro for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* the reason for the discrepancy in the characters is that carriage return and line feed are counted separately so two carriage returns = 4 chars, plus the char you thought you added = 5.

Carriage return + Line feed + Carriage return + Line feed + character

Comment: Less discrepancy and more enthusiasm. Once more, with hidden characters.

Comment: Maybe discrepancy needed some clarification in that there was a discrepancy between our understanding of the character count and what was actually being counted.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take [your most recent edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1551496/list) as an example here...

#### Original:

> Are there any best practices surrounding this practice? I'd be interested to hear others' thoughts on the subject.

#### Revised:

> Are there any best practices surrounding this practice? I'd be interested to hear others' thoughts on the subject.
>
> x

You're not counting the newlines added, which the diff (apparently) is, in the character count.

Comment: That's the one, @benalabaster & I are trying to figure out how other public wiki type sites manage concurrency.

Comment: Who says they do?

Comment: @alex - Well "Last in wins" is a way of managing concurrency.